# Shared Image table with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I would like to create a table for images within my database that can be used by several different models. I'm using entity framework and have defined my images class as follows:

```
public class Images
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }  
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

I would then like to link to this from any of my other models that need to hold an image. E.g

```
public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tImages> Images { get; set; }

}
```

and also

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tImages> Images { get; set; }
}
```

The trouble is that entity framework is adding a foreign key for both project and user to the image table. I kind of expected this I guess.

What I want is to define an image key that can be used to index into my image table. I'm just not sure how to define the classes to get this affect. E.g how do I define my entity classes to acheive the result below:

Project Table

```
//ID    Name        StartDate   EndDate     Image
//1     Project1    05/02/2013  06/04/2013  PROJ01IMG
```

User Table

```
//ID    UserName    Image       
//1     Bob         USER01IMG
```

Image Table

```
//ID  Name          Imagekey    ImageData           Type
//1   img1          PROJ01IMG   0xFFF00F1 .. etc    JPEG
//2   teamphoto     PROJ01IMG   0xFEB0011 ..etc     JPEG
//3   outline       PROJ01IMG   0xFFF0AA3 ..etc     PNG
//4   bob           USER01IMG   0xFFF01233 ..etc    JPEG
```

Of course it may be that having the foreign keys is the correct approach and I shouldn't worry about it? Its just that I have a lot of models and they all need to store images so I'd rather just have them in one table rather than multiple image table as it will make searching/ galleries etc of all images easier down the line I think.

I get the feeling that this a complete noob question and I'm missing something obvious so apologies if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want EF to map a FK, and instead you will manually populate a list based on the image key, define your entities like this. But I think you are better off with what you had, using FK's.

```
public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string ImageKey { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<Image> Images {get; set;}
}

public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public string ImageKey { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]        
    public List<Image> Images {get; set;}
}
```

I suppose you might try defining your classes like this to see if it's what you want:

```
public class Images
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }  
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

}

public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
}
```

That should map a FK to Images in Project as well as in User, which is what I think you're really looking for.

Comment: I think I would understand your answer if you just had String ImageKey which I could set manually against Project and User. I don't understand why you have a list of ImageNames?

Comment: The list is there to be populated so you can, if you wish, easily iterate and display all images associated with Project1, for example.  You could omit, if you like.

Comment: ah ok. I see what you mean with the use of NotMapped. I guess the answer to my question then is that Entity framework won't do that relationship for me.